# Strange `isKindOfClass` behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

With reference to the code below, I have found that `isKindOfClass` is failing to identify a class.

```
id parent = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//parent Can be either 'document' or 'folder'


    NSLog(@"'%@'='%@' ?",[parent class],[Document class]);  
BOOL classCheck = [[parent class] isKindOfClass:[Document class]];  
NSLog (@"%@", classCheck? @"Yes!" : @"No!");
```

Console Log:

> 2011-01-20 10:44:29.746 ApplicationName[906:307] 'Document'='Document' ?
>   2011-01-20 10:44:29.756 ApplicationName[906:307]No!

Has anyone came across this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[parent isKindOfClass:[Document class]]` should return YES. `[parent class]` is a class object which is most likely not an instance of class Document.

Here is why `NSLog()` prints class names (from the docs):

> `+ (NSString *) description`
>
> NSObject's implementation of this
>   method simply prints the name of the
>   class.

Comment: If its not an instance of Document then why would the log show 'Document'='Document'

Comment: As much as the OS might be irrelevant, adding iphone ipad and ios gets a much better view count because they are popular favourite tags

Comment: Because %@ in NSLog calls object's (whatever it is) `description` method, which in this case just returns a class name as a string. Think of it as a coincidence.

Comment: OK, I reverted the tags. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You should be writing: [ parent isKindOfClass: [ Document class ] ]

[ parent class ] will return a Class object and a Class object is not a kind of Document.